# GoogleService failed to initialize in Google Cloud Message

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am using google cloud message in my Android application. I follow the step [here](https://developers.google.com/mobile/add?platform=android&cntapi=signin&cntapp=Default%20Demo%20App&cntpkg=com.google.samples.quickstart.signin&cnturl=https:%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Fidentity%2Fsign-in%2Fandroid%2Fstart%3Fconfigured%3Dtrue&cntlbl=Continue%20with%20Try%20Sign-In)

When i run the app, logcat show the warning messages:

> E/GMPM:  GoogleService failed to initialize, status: 10, Missing an expected resource: 'R.string.google_app_id' for initializing Google services.  Possible causes are missing google-services.json or com.google.gms.google-services gradle plugin.
>
> E/GMPM: Scheduler not set. Not logging error/warn.
>
> E/GMPM: Uploading is not possible. App measurement disabled

But I still can get the token, when i use Google gcm sample code to test push(gcmsender), it is working fine (I can receive the push), I added the configuration file generated by Google called "google-services.json" to my project,
and my app gradle :

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

My project gradle:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.0-beta4'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}
```

I can not figure out why the warning messages shows on logcat, i follow the step and app works fine, does anyone know?

**EDIT**: problem solved,
just add your app id in string.xml file,
[Google console](https://console.developers.google.com/home/dashboard)

find "project_id", and copy to your string.xml

```
<!-- App id -->
<string name="google_app_id">your project id</string>
```

Comment: have you tried to define google_app_id in your string.xml file?

Comment: No, what is google_app_id? I did not find this in GCM guide page

Comment: just define your app id to which you will get from google console.

Comment: Wow! warning disappeared! thank you!

Comment: welcome. :) my pleasure it helped you

Comment: I added the google_app_id in my string.xml but it failed to compile due to a duplicated value, and in fact the google-service.json exported the app id and project_number correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your app id(get it from google console) and add it to string.xml

```
<!-- App id -->
<string name="google_app_id">appId</string>
```

Comment: Where on the developer console do you find the app id? Or are you talking about the Google API Project number?

Comment: @Dimitar Darazhanski yes it is Google API Project number.

Comment: Is there a way to add more than one project number? Otherwise I have to consolidate all the API projects into one.

Comment: @DimitarDarazhanski why you want to add more than one project? you can add multiple project in console.

Comment: I do not want to. But that is how I did it starting several years ago. Now it would be a headache to consolidate them into one.